# LG G2 Lock Screen Size

Tags: lg-g2

I have an LG G2, and I feel a little dumb asking this, but I have seen a G2 with the regular pattern lock screen with the dots (3×3) spanning the whole screen, but mine is much smaller (still a 3×3 but much less space between the dots), and I can't, for the life of me find a way to change this setting. And I dont think he had an app or anything. His phone was a day old, and he hadnt really used it because it didnt work correctly, so we were replacing the phone he had with a new one. Any tips??

Comment: What dots are you talking about? It is possible the other person had installed a 3rd party lock screen, or a custom ROM or a different version of Android even.

Comment: Haha. I guess I should have said the pattern lock, and it just seemed to me (after thoroughly judging him too harshly) that he wouldnt have the slightest clue how to. It was identical to the default screen lock on the phone only more space between the dots.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to lock screen settings and uncheck "Hidden pattern-show pattern dots when tapping on the screen". This will bring back the largee dots.

This is different from "make pattern visible" which is at tthe bottom of the lock screen options page.